# Failsafe report modification 'classname' field

Tags: java, maven, report, maven-failsafe-plugin

Can't find the way how to modify xml report from maven-surefire plugin. I am using Junit 5 , maven-failsafe-plugin 3.0.0-M5
with configuration:

```
<plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <statelessTestsetReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5Xml30StatelessReporter">
                                <disable>false</disable>
                                <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
                                <usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>true</usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>
                                <usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>
                                <usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>
                            </statelessTestsetReporter>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

My actual report:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite >
  <properties>
    ...
  </properties>
  <testcase name="This comes from @DisplayName()" classname="com.my.project.ClassName" time="0.945"/>
</testsuite>
```

Would like to have in the end something like this. Field classname will contain full path to the method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite >
  <properties>
    ...
  </properties>
  <testcase name="This comes from @DisplayName()" classname="com.my.project.ClassName.testMethodName" time="0.945"/>
</testsuite>
```

Maybe some one have similar expirience

Comment: Why do you like to change that report?

Comment: @khmarbaise the report will be used to generate traceability matrix so I would like to have full class name + method name.

Comment: classname cannot be a method name. So this is the answer. Sorry!
We wouldn't change this. But you can change it, and that;s the reason why we segregated the API and impl to the separate JARs. So please implement your own class, satisfying the super types. See this section implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5Xml30StatelessReporter">